# How to correctly pause the movements of sprites in a SpriteKit game?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a simple SpriteKit game, and in the appDelegate file in the`applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)`function, I put the code:`GameScene().physicsWorld.speed = 0.0`. However, when I close and reopen the app, a SKSpriteNode with a physicsBody attached carries on falling. I have also tried adding both these lines of code:
`GameScene().speed = 0`, 
`GameScene().paused = true`. None of this works though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: pausing should work. Where are you pausing it?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pause the `SKView`

```
self.scene?.view?.paused = true
```

Add an observer in your view controller, holding the view, for the willResignActive notification and then pause the SKView.

Add the observer for willEnterForeground to start it.

Comment: Perfect solution, the problem was that I was trying to pause the appDelegate file, which is just ridiculous. so thanks :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :)